# c++ trouble using sort for struct

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, struct

I got a struct that a user can define what string values go in where. I've tried ordering it alphabetically but had no luck with what research I found online. I was hoping if one of use can see where im going wrong

libraries being used : iostream, string, fstream and algorithm

```
struct House
{
    int room_num;               
    string person;      
};

struct compare_by_word
{
    bool operator()(const House& lhs, const House& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.person < rhs.person;
    }
};
```

I get errors on this line, by the way im using visual studios 2010

```
  void asc_order()
    {
        sort(data.begin(), data.end(), compare_by_word());
//for loop will be displayed here to show table
    }
```

Errors I get:

Error: Identifier data is undefined

struct compare_by_word
Error: type name is not allowed

Comment: data should be declared. We assumed this code is just a snippet. for demonstration. You need to have something like `vector<House> data;` in your code somewhere in side `asc_order` before calling `sort`. Hopefully filling it with some Houses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an instance of `compare_by_word`. This is done by calling its constructor:

```
std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(), compare_by_word());
//                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[***Live Demo***](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4yc7Hy$3228)

I also see that you're not compiling with any headers that introduce an object with a `begin` or `end` method. These are commonly used in vectors and other dynamic containers. So I think you should try passing the address range instead as feasible alternative:

```
std::size_t len = sizeof(data)/sizeof(*data);

std::sort(data, data + len, compare_by_word());
```

[***Live Demo***](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4yc7Hy$3238)

Or if you're compiling in C++11 you can pass a [lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/.../what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11) callback in place of an explicit functor and use the [`begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) library functions instead of the address range:

```
using std::begin;
using std::end;

std::sort(begin(data), end(data), [] (House const& lhs, House const& rhs)
{
    return lhs.person < rhs.person;
});
```

[***Live Demo***](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4yc7Hy$3239)

Comment: You should... reorder the elements in your example. It works great, but it doesn't really show that the sort is doing anything.

Comment: @Xymostech Yeah, maybe I should mix them up a bit. :)

Comment: thanks for that david! Never used OO programming before so sorry about newbish stuff,

Just wondering if you could show me a live example with 

std::size_t len = sizeof(data)/sizeof(*data);

std::sort(data, data + len, compare_by_word());

Thanks, when i tried it it tells me data is undefined =/

Comment: @Bobski Sure give me a second. :)

Comment: [Here you go](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4yc7Hy$3238). Basically [`std::size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) is an unsigned integer type used for holding the size of things.

Comment: Thanks for that and the after help. Really appreciate the time you took to help me out!

Answer (score 2):

You're passing the **type** as comparator. You need to pass **object** of `compare_by_word` as comparator to `sort`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be

```
struct compare_by_word
{
    bool operator()(const House& lhs, const House& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.person < rhs.person;
    }
} compare_by_word;  // Here.
```

Comment: to the answers provided before me

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in **sort** statement.Replace it by:

```
sort(&data[0],&data[5],compare_by_word());
```

**[DEMO AT IDEONE](http://ideone.com/LabS0o)**